# SharePoint 2013 - Verify Active Directory security group membership in Master Page javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-services, security

I desire to add some JavaScript that will verify the current users AD security group membership.  If a member of group 'A' the logic will redirect one way.  If not in group 'A', but in group 'B' the logic will direct another way.  If in neither security group a warning will be displayed and no redirect will occur.

How can I verify the current users security groups using JavaScript in SharePoint 2013?  I assume there are SharePoint web services that expose current user security values...

Comment: Look into "SPServices".  A very smart man built this for us to make it easier to do exactly what you are looking for:

https://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks to be answered before on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m

Comment: @Kolten - thanks for the references to another framework.  Looks like the scope of my effort to identify a suitable solution just got larger...

Comment: @Ransher Singh - the answer you suggest is not the same question - I am seeing to identify the current users AD security groups.  I have no need to identify the current users sharepoint groups.  Perhaps my question is not clear.  Will edit the question for clarity - thanks!